# Is it possible to make data.table code faster?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table

I've decided to rewrite my code from dplyr to data.table as I've heard it's faster.

Surprisingly, I managed to gain only an insignificant speedup in execution time. Are my data too small or I wrote in a horrible data.table style?

Results are the same except for the class of the output.

I did not use setDT() on purpose as it would be subjective.

EDIT: I made a similar reproducible example.

```
pacman::p_load(gapminder, data.table, dplyr, stringr, microbenchmark)

gapminder -> gapminder
as_tibble(gapminder) -> gapminder_tibble
as.data.table(gapminder) -> gapminder_data.table

microbenchmark(
  dplyr = {
    gapminder_tibble %>% 
      filter(year > 1900, year < 1990) %>% 
      mutate(country = str_sub(str_to_lower(country), 5)) %>% 
      count(country)
  },

  data.table = {
    gapminder_data.table[year > 1900 & year < 1990][, country := str_sub(str_to_lower(country), 5)][, .(n = .N), by = country]
  },

  times = 1000
)
```

Data.table code is even slower...

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
      dplyr 2.441601 2.756801 3.165089 2.965350 3.181802 29.1171  1000  a 
 data.table 2.646601 3.101201 3.548372 3.383252 3.661500 11.9474  1000   b
```

Why is that? How to make it faster? Any advice? What is the fastest way of writing it in data.table?

Comment: You can `setkey` to make it run a bit more faster

Comment: Depends largely on how many rows your performing this. I use data.table usually with more than 100.000 rows. When dealing with 1.000.000 and more the difference is quite significant. In your case, especially mutate and group_by (within count) should be more performant in data.table.

Comment: When you are performing benchmarks, make certain that you are comparing apples with apples. Currently you are using `as.data.table` for each iteration, causing some (slight but maybe not insignificant) overhead. The comparison should only be of the core problem, having done any `up front and only once` work prior to the microbenchmark.

Comment: Would be useful if you made a reproducible example.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I changed the code.

Comment: 3 milliseconds is already so fast that this example doesn't illustrate a situation where an improvement in speed would be necessary. Usually with larger data and certain operations there is some benefit, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify a bit by avoiding (the unnecessary) chaining and switching the order of operations of `str_to_lower()` and `str_sub()` (no need to convert to lowercase letters that we are dropping anyway)

```
gapminder_data.table[year > 1900 & year < 1990, 
                     .(n = .N), 
                     by = .(country = str_to_lower(str_sub(country, 5)))]
```